# Inverse Fourier transform of equation to define a wavelet

Tags: fourier-transform, wavelets

First time asking the internet a question...

I am trying to learn wavelet analyses using the filter bank method described in this article (https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1050641100000304). I have the following function which defines a wavelet in frequency space:

$$F \psi (f,cf,scale):=(\frac{f}{\text{cf}})^{\text{cf}\cdot scale}\cdot e^{(\frac{-f}{\text{cf}}+1)\cdot \text{cf} \cdot scale}$$

where f is the frequency in Fourier space, scale=0.3 and for this particular wavelet, cf=6.90. I am trying to take the inverse Fourier transform of this to get into time space. However, I am not sure what form that function would take, or how to derive the correct form. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Any suggestions for resources to learn more would be appreciated as well.

Comment: complex(2-sided) Fourier Transform or Inverse Fourier Transform of $x^a e^{-b x}$ is not readily available.